# Any Issues, concerns on having a Stored Procedure in Subscriber Database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactional-replication

I have a database (ms-sql) that is replicated(transactional) to a subscriber.

I'd like to add a stored procedure to the **subscriber only**

Is this possible?
Does it affect replication?
Any potential Issues?
Under what circumstance could the sp be erased/cleared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscriber can have different set of objects than publisher. Its perfectly fine to have a stored procedure on subscriber ONLY.

@Tara is correct, it wont drop the proc at the subscriber when you reinitialize the publication.

The only time that I think you would have to remember to recreate the SP is when you have to [Initialize a Transactional Subscription from a Backup of publisher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147834.aspx) .

Comment: it won't overwrite the stored procedure on the subscriber if it isn't included in replication on the publisher. It doesn't just wipe out all objects. It touches only those objects that are being replicated.

Comment: When the publisher is reinitialized it will delete the sp @ the subscriber (non-existant at the publisher)?

Comment: @pmeyer, it won't drop the stored procedure on the subscriber.